# Kinect v1 with Processing to .obj to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, processing, kinect

I want to create an hologram that is exported via the kinect to an hololense. But it's very slow.

I use [this](http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/) tutorial to collect point cloud data, and [this](http://n-e-r-v-o-u-s.com/tools/obj/) library to export my data as a 3D object in .obj format. The library that exports obj doesnt accept points so I had to draw little triangles. I save the files .obj .png and .mtl on my local xampp.

Next, I download the files with a unity script and WWW object. I also use Runtime OBJ Importer from unity's asset store to create a 3D object at runtime.

The last part is to export the unity app on a hololense. (I will do it next).

But before that, 
The process is working but is very slow. I want the hologram to be fluid. A lot of time is wasted :

- take depth and rgb data of the kinect
- export data to an obj png and mtl file
- download the files on unity as frequent as possible
- render the files

I think of streaming but does unity need a complet obj file to render ? If I compress .png to .jpg will a gain some time ?

Do you have some pointers to help me ?

Comment: FYI: It sounds like you have functional code, that is just not up to the performance level you desire. Review of functional code (and explicitly for performance) is on-topic for [codereview.se]. However, you have to actually put your code in the question (which is generally a requirement here too).

Comment: Thank you, let's say the code is very basic I am using the libraries and tutorials I mention. But my problem is the strategy and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the way your question is phrased is confusing: it's unclear wether you want to record point clouds that you later load and render in Unity or you want to somehow stream the point cloud with the aligned RGB texture in close to realtime to Unity.

You initial attempts are using Processing.

In terms of recording data, I recommend using the [SimpleOpenNI library](https://github.com/wexstorm/simple-openni) which can record both depth and RGB data to an .oni file (see the [RecorderPlay example](https://github.com/wexstorm/simple-openni/blob/master/SimpleOpenNI/examples/OpenNI/RecorderPlay/RecorderPlay.pde)).

Once you have a recording, you can loop through each frame and for each frame store the vertices to a file.

In terms of saving to .obj you'll need to convert the point cloud to a mesh (triangulate the vertices in 3D).

Another option would be to store the point cloud to a format like [.ply](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/).
You can find more info on writing to a .ply file in Processing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570247/kinect-processing-simple-openni-point-cloud-data-not-being-output-properly/11583262#11583262)

In terms of streaming the data, this will be complicated:

- if you stream all the vertices it that's a lot of data: up to 921600 floats ( (640 x 480 = 307200) * 3)
- if you stream both depth (11bit 640x480) and RGB (8bit 640x480) images that will be even more data.
  One option might be to only send the vertices that have a depth and overall skipping points (e.g. send every 3rd point). In terms of sending the data you can try [OSC](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/)

Once you get the points in Unity you should be able to [render a point cloud in Unity](http://www.kamend.com/2014/05/rendering-a-point-cloud-inside-unity/)

What would be ideal in terms of network performance is a codec (compressor/decompressor) for the depth data. I haven't used one thus far, but doing a quick I see there are options like [this one](https://github.com/arturoc/kinectStreaming)(very date).
You'll need to do a bit of research and see what kinect v1 depth streaming libraries are out there already, test and see what works best for your scenario.
Ideally, if the library is written in C# there's a chance you'll be able to use it to decode the received in Unity.

Comment: Thank you for you answer,

Yes I want real time transmission to see an hologram in the hololense.

I used Shiffman's library as it was the first and it works. Do you mean that simple-openni is faster ?

I use ObjExporter but it doesnt work with points, so I have to create little triangles to save an .obj file with .png for textures and .mtl. Do you think the .ply approach is better ?

I am trying to find the bottleneck, is it my comptuer, is it Unity or Processing. I am still learning, thank you very very much for you pointers.

Comment: The only reason I was recommending SimpleOpenNI is for the built-in serialisation: the ability to easily save/load depth+RGB streams. If you need to this in realtime, there's no real reason to it. You're getting pointcloud data just fine using the KinectP5 library. Try streaming a lower resolution version of the valid point clouds and rendering that in Unity (as vertices, not as a triangulated mesh). See what the performance is like. If in terms of visuals/performance that is ok, look into streaming the texture(either the whole thing, or a list of values just for the lo-res 3d points)

Comment: ...otherwise you may need to find a depth map codec to use over the network, which is a bit more hardcore if you're still learning, but the point of codecs is they deal with the nitty gritty data compression/decompression. If the answer was helpful, feel free to vote and or mark it as you see fit ;)